# Invalid syntax error - Python 3.5.2 Django 1.10

Tags: syntax-error, python-3.5

Python/Django newcomer here. Im getting a syntax error with the following code, can anyone help me out here? IDLE3 highlights Line 16 "Treasure" just before ("Fool's Gold").

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'treasures':treasures})

class Treasure:
    def __init__(self, name, value, material, location):
        self.name = name
        self.value = value
        self.material = material
        self.location = location

treasures = [
    Treasure('Gold Nugget', 500.00, 'gold', "Curley's Creek, NM")
    Treasure("Fool's Gold", 0, 'pyrite', "Fool's Falls, CO")
    Treasure('Coffee Can', 20.00, 'tin', 'Acme, CA')
]
```

Comment: Missing comas between Treasure objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to put commas after the elements of the array. Like this:

```
treasures = [
    Treasure('Gold Nugget', 500.00, 'gold', "Curley's Creek, NM"),
    Treasure("Fool's Gold", 0, 'pyrite', "Fool's Falls, CO"),
    Treasure('Coffee Can', 20.00, 'tin', 'Acme, CA')
]
```

Comment: Indeed I needed to put commas after the elements in the array...It had been a long day! Thanks Jean-François Fabre and Runner.